# Why haven't I the mortarboard badge?

Tags: support

As you can see on [my reputation history](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/17592/camil-staps?tab=reputation), on January 8, I got 266 reputation. I believe I should get the [mortarboard badge](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/badges/25/mortarboard) for that, but [I don't have it](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/17592/camil-staps?tab=badges).

Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Just a guess, but 100 of that was a association bonus, which probably doesn't count towards the earned points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the 200 reputation counter only considers regular vote reputation, not association bonus, bounty bonus or answer-accepted reputation points.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting the Stack Overflow [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) for badges :

> Earned at least 200 reputation in a single day. All reputation
>   activities, including up and down votes, accepted answers, bounties,
>   and suggested edits count towards this badge except for association
>   bonuses, which do not count.

Which is mentioned in this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/200868).